# Monotonicity of a function without using differentiation

Tags: calculus

I want to prove the monotonicity of the following function WITHOUT using derivatives.

f(x)=x²-4x+3, on the interval [-1,1]

let x1 be less than x2

square  both sides

x1² less than x2²

add -4x to both sides.

x1²-4x1>x2²-4x2

ADD 3 :    x1²-4x1+3>x2²-4x2+3

f(x1)>f(x2)

so because we started with x1 less than x2 and ended with f(x1)>f(x2) the function is strictly decreasing.

Any ideas whether this is correct, and if there are any other ways of solving this without differentiating.

Comment: I have not read your argument carefully. That said, I don't see where you use the fact that $-1 \le x_1 < x_2 \le 1$. You must use that somewhere, since the statement is false without a restriction like that. Please [edit] the question to use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: i used it in the beggining, started with x1<x2 and ended with f(x1)>f(x2)

Comment: $x_1<x_2$ doesn't imply $x_1^2<x_2^2$, even within the interval provided, as -1<1, but $(-1)^2=1^2$

Answer (score 1):

Take $y<x$. If the following inequality is satisfied, the function is monotonically decreasing:

$y^2-4y+3 > x^2-4x+3$

First, note that adding a constant does not affect the result, so we can ignore the $3$. We just need to examine whether the following is true:

$y^2-4y > x^2-4x.$

You can then do some elementary manipulations:

$y^2-4y > x^2-4x \Leftrightarrow y^2-x^2 > 4y-4x \Leftrightarrow (y+x)(y-x) > 4(y-x).$

Now, what can you say based on that last inequality?

Answer:

> $y-x$ is a negative number because $y<x$, and $y+x$ is smaller than $2$ because $x,y \in [-1,1]$. That should be enough for you to conclude that $(y+x)(y-x) > 4(y-x)$ is true.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=x^2-4x+3=(x-2)^2-1$, so f attains its minimum at $x=2$, so when $x\le 2, x-2\le 0 $ is increasing and thus $f(x)=(x-2)^2-1$ is decreasing, hence f is decreasing on $[-1,1]$.